# Customizar RatingBar - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xml, xamarin

Estoy tratando de customizar el componente `RatingBar` en `Xamarin.Android`. Si dejo el componente tal cual se genera (solo con el width, height y numStars) funciona excelente.

El problema aca es que las estrellas son demasiado grandes y se ve grotesco si se deja así, por lo que he intentado disminuir el height, pero las estrellas quedan cortadas casi a la mitad; entonces intente utilizar varios `style`s, y se ve bien en el diseñador XML, pero al correr la app el componente no funciona (no se mueven las estrellas, no se puede seleccionar ninguna).

Alguna idea?

```
<RatingBar
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
                        android:progressTint="#FFCC01"
                        android:id="@+id/RatingBar1" />
```

[image: Diseño]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a utilizar el factor de escala, lo puedes ir modificando para adaptarlo al tamaño que deseas. !.0 sería su tamaño normal. Todo lo que esté por debajo lo disminuirá, y todo lo que esté por encima, lo aumentará

```
Android:scaleX="0.5"
Android:scaleY="0.5"
//------------------Modifica a tu elección
Android:scaleX=".8"
Android:scaleY=".8"
```

Puedes hacer que se desplace del margen la medida que deseas empleando

```
Android:transformPivotX="0dp"
Android:transformPivotY="0dp"
```

Usando StyleSmall pondrás el menor tamaño posible de barra

```
style = "?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo solucione con la escala: -- Android:scaleX="0.5"
Android:scaleY="0.5" -- ya que a como mencione en el post si utilizo cualquier style el componente deja de funcionar.   Ahora lo que estoy revisando es que no me quiere reconocer la propiedad de numStars; lo seteo en 5 y me aparecen muchas siempre. Compartire la solucion cuando la encuentre. Saludos